# How can I change the pythonpath on `uvicorn` execution?

Tags: openapi-generator, uvicorn

I generated a FastAPI project and all imports are relative to the `src` folder:

```
├── src
│   └── openapi_server
│       ├── apis
│       ├── main.py
│       ├── models
│       ├── __pycache__
│       └── security_api.py
```

So, I have basically two options:

1. Fix all relative imports
2. Fix pythonpath

How can I change the pythonpath on `uvicorn` execution? I found https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/619 which I thought was the solution, but

```bash
~/.../src$ uvicorn main:main --reload --app-dir openapi_server/
```

didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done how it's regularly done in python. Therefore, you can simply use:

```
~/.../src$ uvicorn openapi_server.main:main --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

uvicorn src.openapi_server.main:app --pythonpath src

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).